# Organizing task results using print statements

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I am sending urls the are in a list using the task, BeginGetResponse, EndGetResponse and fromasync, and continuewith methods. Using Console.WriteLine is there a way to organize/schedule each urls results when they come back? When I try to handle this the print statements are out of sync.

Example:

1.url:google.com
    -ResponseStatus: up
    -Sent time
    -Received Time
2. url yahoo.com
etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the results in a particular order, rather than in the order that they happen to complete, then don't add the print statements in `ContinueWith` calls to each task.  Instead call `WhenAll` on a collection of all of the tasks and then add a continuation to *that* which prints all of the values.

```
public static void AddPrintStatements(IEnumerable<Task<string>> tasks)
{
    Task.WhenAll(tasks)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            foreach (var line in t.Result)
                PrintResults(line);
        });
}
```

Since you're using 4.0 and don't have a `WhenAll`, you can use this instead:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> WhenAll<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(),
        results => results.Select(t => t.Result));
}
```

If you want the results to be printed as they come in, but also maintaining their order, then you could do that too by going through each task and adding a continuation that is both of the previous continuation and the given task:

```
public static void AddPrintStatements2(IEnumerable<Task<string>> tasks)
{
    Task continuation = Task.FromResult(true);

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        continuation = continuation.ContinueWith(t =>
            task.ContinueWith(t2 => PrintResults(t2.Result)))
            .Unwrap();
    }
}
```

Since you're using 4.0 you also won't have `FromResult`, so you can use this:

```
public static Task<T> FromResult<T>(T result)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    tcs.SetResult(result);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Ok so in my code i have a HttpWebRequest myReq Task<WebResponse> task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(myReq.BeginGetResponse, myReq.EndGetResponse, null); task.ContinueWith(t => { //print statements });

Where do I put those methods you discussed if my print statements are called in the continueWith?

Comment: @DeVonte Then either use the appropriate continuations before passing the tasks into this method, or modify these methods based on what your tasks actually return.

Comment: Ok so in my code i have a HttpWebRequest myReq Task<WebResponse> task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(myReq.BeginGetResponse, myReq.EndGetResponse, null); task.ContinueWith(t => { //print statements }); Where do I put those methods you discussed if my print statements are called in the continueWith?

Comment: @DeVonte You take the tasks created from `FromAsync` and put them into a collection, such as a `List`.  Then pass them into this method.  THis method has a `PrintResults` method that you can define to do your printing.

Comment: Ok I will see what I can do

Comment: I understand that I have to take the task created from async and put them into a list and pass them into the method. But should that be outside the .continuewith method or inside?

Comment: I created a List<Task> taskList however when I try to pass that into AddPrintStatements it gives me an invalid arguments error. Do I need to change something in the parameter of AddPrintStatements?

Comment: @DeVonte Look at the error.  Look at the signature of this method; it doesn't accept a list of tasks, it accepts a list of tasks that have a result of a given type.  They need to match.